# I want multiple rows in into single row

Tags: sql

i have a data in databse like this

[image: Database data]

and i want to pivot it or want a result like this

[image: Desire result]

Comment: That's actually bad design imho.

Comment: #Umair Ikhtiar, do you want to pivot only 2 rows or more?

Comment: What's the logic for having these seemingly unrelated items on the same row?

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different, unrelated software packages produced by different companies. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: And if there is a third row in your source, do you want a `mealname3` column (etc) in your output? (short answer: you can't have that)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a salf join

```
select 
    a.IDX
    , a.mealname
    , a.menuname
    , a.venuename
    , b.mealname
    , b.menuname
    , b.venuename
  from my_table a
  inner join my_table b on a.date = b.date and b.mealid=2 
  where a.mealid= 1
```